Does Sub panel need ground rod?
Have a Outside Main Box that's Full. Want to add Outside Sub-Panel right next to it 12 inches to the right. I know the Sub-Panel uses separate Neutral Bar and Ground Bar. But, Does the Sub-Panel need it's own Grounding Rod into the earth?

Buy a much bigger sub-panel than you think you need. "Price of a pizza now" .vs. "painful regret later." i.e. only the difference in price between two panels of different sizes, rather than having to add a third panel later, or swap out a smaller panel for a larger panel later.

If the existing main panel is a still-supported brand/type, get a subpanel of the same brand/type. That way you can move circuits between the panels easily, which may come in handy for a bunch of reasons in the future. And put at least two nice big metal conduits connecting them so you can have both the feed wires and wires for individual circuits going between the boxes as needed.

No.
A subpanel only needs its own ground rod when it is in another building not attached to the building with the main panel.
There could be an argument for an additional ground rod if the subpanel is on the opposite side of a large building. But definitely not when the panels are side-by-side.
